# Wordpress ecommerce site taking 9 seconds to load

Tags: php, wordpress, load-time, stripe-payments, woocommerce

I have a site which is taking 9 seconds to load any of the page. Upon the request, the page hangs for about 9 seconds and then it is served. I'm trying to figure out whether it's a problem with the wordpress installation, something with the host ... or what.

Site: http://www.drawingwithconfidence.com

Comment: Hire a developer. When you have toothache you visit dentist, don't you? So do the same if you have issues with your code.

Comment: The majority time is with your web server serving the html - which took 9.99 seconds when I tried - so giving us the URL won't help. We need to know what's going on when generating the page.

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a lot of out going sources, which would slow down the site. One big source which takes a little bit of the time which is /shopping-cart/#.UDC8a6Ie7nM it takes 3.5 seconds to load up which is kind of weird as its a 22kb file, another file which is 88kb takes like 800 milli seconds to load up. So which bumps up my curiosity, why so long?... I would love to check out the code of that.

Um also you get some font's from google's web font service and that takes quite a long time, Why do you use this, easy to read font's are on the computer all ready, all the fancy one's that are hard to read and stuff are custom fonts.

For a quick answer don't out source all you link's yes it is safer but it does ruin the website speed. If you want to you could try it with out the shopping-cart, but then you remove the e-commercial part but it is the slowest part of the site.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 possible suggestions:

1. If the Ecommerce plugin is slowing down the pages, use a different one. There are many Ecommerce plugins for WordPress.
2. If the page is slow without the Ecommerce plugin, use a dedicated Ecommerce solution such as Zen Cart, OS commerce etc.

If your hosting provides CPanel, it should be fairly easy to try some Ecommerce solutions before changing. Just install them with Fantastico or Installatron into a sub-directory for trial purposes.